# TreeView as a DateTemplate couldn't display correct data

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, treeview, datatemplate

I have a `ListView`, and its `DataTemplate` is two rows `Grid`, first row is a `button`, second row is a `treeview`.

The treeview's `ItemsSource` bind to a `List<T>` collection in my `ViewModel`.

When I click the button, create the List, and display the treeview. But if there're many `ListViewItem`, when I click the first ListViewItem's button, the treeview display correct, when I click the Button in the second ListViewItem, the treeview in the first ListViewItem will changed to the same data with the second one.

Any solution can help me? I want each `treeview` display their own data.

Comment: could not understand ", the first ListView's treeview will changed two the sample data with the second one" and you will need to share your template and code how are setting and filling the ItemsSource of treeview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are creating the list which is the `ItemsSource` of `TreeView` in your `ViewModel` and you have binded the `TreeView` in `ItemTemplate` to this `List`. Hence all the `TreeViews` are binded to the same collection and changing it will change the `ItemsSource` of all the Trees.

The solution to this is to create this `List` inside the `Model` which is backing your `ListViewItem` and bind it to the `TreeView`. In `ViewModel` you can update the `List` which your selected model contains. In this way every item will have its own `ItemsSource` for TreeView.